# How to save Drools KieSessions?

Tags: java, drools, kie

I have more than 1000 rules to do inference. As the drools will process these rules in RETE algorithm before do inference, I found it cost so much time to do this and I know it is necessary. But I want it could be faster.So is these any way can store the KieSession to DataBase so that I could load it next time if I want to use it? I read the Drools Documentation Chapter 4.2.4.9 for Drools 6.3 but I still feel puzzled.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: You know how to obtain a KieBase? Good. Write it to an ObjectOutputStream. For faster startup, read it via an ObjectInputStream and proceed as if it were newly compiled.

Comment: you mean that I build a file to store it?

Comment: You make it sound difficult. It isn't.

Comment: @launehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458536/drools-6-1-0-final-setting-for-kiemodulerepo-purge-behavior please have a look.

Comment: Thanks for your help