# Drools: Reusing Same Kiesession For Multiple Requests

Tags: java, drools

I have more than 1000 rules currently (and can expand later) which are used to create KieBuilder through an excel file. After this I am creating a StatelessKieSession which I am using for all the requests coming to my server(server supports concurrent requests). Creating KieBuilder and StatelessKieSession takes some time so that is why I want to keep both of these already setup so that when request comes, I only need to execute the rules, keeping response time of the request as low as possible. But creating a new StatelessKieSession for every request increases my server latency. I am not an expert in using Drools so wanted to know if this is the correct approach?

Idea is that whenever my rules are changed, I will replace current KieBuilder and replace the existing StatelessKieSession which will be used to process requests after that time.
I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772553/drools-same-kiesession-for-multiple-requests) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180857/how-to-save-drools-kiesessions) questions but couldn't find closure to my doubt.
Everywhere I checked it's mentioned to always create a new StatelessKiession but when I tried the above approach of re-using same kieSession, I was able to get the desired results(I ran small perf-test with concurrent requests).

Is this approach fine?
Sharing Code Snippet:

```
StatelessKieSession kieSession;

private void initKieSession(String filePath) {
        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
        Resource dt
                = ResourceFactory
                .newClassPathResource(filePath,
                        getClass());
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem().write(dt);
        KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
        kieBuilder.buildAll();
        if(kieBuilder.getResults().hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR) || kieBuilder.getResults().hasMessages(Message.Level.WARNING)) {
            log.debug("[initKieSession] Issue while loading rules.");
            return;
        }


        KieRepository kieRepository = kieServices.getRepository();
        ReleaseId krDefaultReleaseId = kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId();
        KieContainer kieContainer
                = kieServices.newKieContainer(krDefaultReleaseId);
        kieSession = kieContainer.newStatelessKieSession();
    }

public RulesDto executeRules(RulesDto rulesInput) {
        kieSession.execute(rulesInput);
        return rulesInput;
}
```

Comment: The usual way is to share and reuse the kbase, not the ksession.

Comment: That's what I am not able to understand. Why can't we reuse the kiesession? Even when I tested, I was able to get the expected results.

Comment: Because KieSessions are designed along the same principles as database connections. You're not _supposed_ to reuse them like that. For high volume applications where you're constantly creating new sessions and invoking them, there's session pools (similar to db connection pools) you can use to optimize the creation/destruction process to avoid bottlenecks.

Comment: Also you might not be aware of it, but the Stateless session's `execute` method calls `dispose` under the covers so the session _has_ been disposed of once you execute.

Comment: Thanks @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas. This provides some clarity. I will try exploring session pools.
Regarding Stateless session's dispose call under execute method call, yes I checked this. Internally it creates a new session ([this](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/master/drools-core/src/main/java/org/drools/core/impl/StatelessKnowledgeSessionImpl.java#L288)) and calls dispose method at the end of every call. Somehow new session creation inside stateless session isn't taking that much time.